# how to integrate .jrxml files to a project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jasper-reports

I have approximately 5 jrxml files and many jsp files in a project.Now i have to integrate jrxml files to a project present in eclipse.

Now, how to integrate jrxml files to eclipse so that it should be directory independant (it should not be like this eg:-D:/dev/tools/jasper files/report11.jrxml)?

The second question is we have to include both *.jrxml* and *.jasper* files?

The third question is "if we open the project which is present in eclipse in another person PC by pasting this url (http://192.1.168.201:8080/SalesProject/) in other person PC it should run normally and should run jrxml files and should display the data in different formats (eg:-PDF,DOC,XLS,XLSX)

Comment: I have modified answer so you see how to get context in jsf

Comment: @PetterFriberg While running the server i am getting an error like    **"invalid byte 1 of 1-byte utf-8 sequence"**

Comment: My code is `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marketing_database","root","root");
 ServletContext context = request.getServletContext(); 
 String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/report10.jasper");
 InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fullPath));
 JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);`

Comment: @PetterFriberg its working.I kept both **.jrxml** and **.jasper** files in `/WEB-INF/reports/` and in code,i added **.jrxml** file as `String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/report10.jrxml");`.In eclipse as the eclipse-browser is just like Internet Explorer so its working in eclipse-browser as well as IE9,but when i am accessing through **Google-Chrome** only PDF is working but DOC,XLS,XLSX not working. Is there any Browser-dependancy

Comment: Check what you pass in header to browser, it should work on chrome as well.

Comment: @PetterFriberg    I passed this `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>DOC Page</title>
</head>`

Comment: When you pass the doc and xls check that you have correct application header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95441/discussion-between-chitti-oneterahertz-and-petter-friberg).

Comment: Sorry I'm at a client today, can't sped to much time, tomorrow we can discuss

Comment: @PetterFriberg Yeah sure. Have a nice day.Sorry for sending you a mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Where to put them? In a folder that is **deployed on server** as you do with your jsp, images web-inf ecc.
2. Do I need both `.jrxml` and `.jasper`?, No `.jasper` is enough (note: naturally in your server code you should not compile the .jrxml files anymore). To make it easier to understand a comparisons with java would be `.jrxml = .java` and `.jasper = .class`
3. Will it work? Sure since they are deployed on the server you only need to figure out how to reference them correctly from your .jsf page (search some one the web or on SO, there are a lot of answers) ...

   ```
   ServletContext context = request.getServletContext(); 
   String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports/your_report.jasper");
   ```